# why is mypython class undefined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i ran my python code in cmd dos,and it returned err like this below

```
 File "counts.py", line 3, in <module>
 class Student(object):
File "counts.py", line 11, in Student
if Student.count != 0:
NameError: name 'Student' is not defined
```

and this is my python code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
class Student(object):
  count = 0
  def init(self,name):
    self.name = name
    Student.count += 1  
    if Student.count != 0:
      print('test fail')
    else:
      elson = Student('elson')
      if Student.count != 1:
          print('fail')
      else:
        print('there are %d student'%Student.count)
        print('succeed')
```

i've got confuesd for a while and dont know what to do ,thanks for all the replying

Comment: a) When you say you ran Python in cmd dos, did you invoke it by `python counts.py`, or else please post your exact command line? b) Was this Python 3.x or 2.x? (`class Student(object):` is Python 2.x) c) Can you run other Python code? Try to run any other Python file and tell us if you can. d) Try running the builtin IDLE interpreter instead, and post your code into that, please confirm that works. To eliminate issues like DOS/Windows path, environment PYTHONPATH, multiple conflicting Python versions, etc.

Comment: post your full code, show us where the main function is. There can be a hundred possibilities of things getting wrong.

Comment: it is a full one.

Comment: i found the answer.it's beacuz i use ultraedit to write the code,and ultraedit doesn't have a good python support as vscode does

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved , i found out it's because the support of my ultraedit has some problem. i typed it in vscode and everything went well

Answer (score 0):

In case your code is exactly as you posted, I found a few problems (starting, first, with the fact that I couldn't understand exactly which output you're looking for, so please update me in case nothing I write here make sense for you, so I can re-write my answer):
1) Your indentation is wrong, so your functions are out of the class.

2) When you call the object inside of its function, you should use `self` and not the class name, in the case `Student`.

3) You're mixing the class declaration with the object instantiation, so when you add the following code, it seems for me you're trying to instantiate an object inside of the object declaration, meaning, even if it would work, you could create an infinite loop:

```
if Student.count != 0:
        print('test fail')
else :
    elson = Student('elson')
```

The solution would be to change all the `Student.` when writing inside the class, and add `self.` instead, such as:

```
def init(self,name):
  self.name = name
  self.count += 1 # or count +=1
```

PS: You could use a class method as well, if what you want is to iterate the number of objects instantiated, and update the count this way. Just add `@classmethod` before the method that iterates the count.

Comment: thanks for helping,but i tried your solution and it returned me the same err warning

Comment: @hughtainWong I didn't write the full code, so I need to understand better what's your purpose with mixing those concepts, because I cannot grasp what you were trying to do there. Detail better so I can post the full code here

Comment: it is already a full code(lol) sorry i'm just a very new newbie

Comment: i think i just found the problems

Comment: it's beacuz i use ultraedit to write the code,and ultraedit doesn't have a good python support as vscode does

Comment: In case your problem is not solved, let me know. 
But explaining the details of what you're trying to accomplish, so I can help you with full code @hughtainWong